# Matlab out of memory bug

Tags: matlab

I am faced with some memory troubles when I have tried to use this function that I created in MATLAB:

```
fn = @(k,n) symsum((-1)^l*factorial(2^l)/factorial(2^l-2^k),l,k,n)
```

Up until this point, nothing goes wrong but when I applied the function with `k=2` and `n=4`, I get the following:

```
fn(2,4)
??? Error using ==> factorial at 17
N must be a matrix of non-negative integers.

Error in ==> @(k,n)symsum((-1)^l*factorial(2^l)/factorial(2^l-2^k),l,k,n)
```

other times it is the following :

```
Error using ==> mupadmex
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.evalin at 119
                [res,status] = mupadmex(statement);

Error in ==> mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.feval at 157
            [S,err] = evalin(engine,stmt);

Error in ==> mupadfeval at 24
    [S,err] = feval(symengine,cmd,varargin{:}); % returns sym

Error in ==> sym.mpower at 22
   B = mupadfeval('_power',A,p);

Error in ==> @(k,n)symsum((-1)^l*factorial(2^l)/factorial(2^l-2^k),l,k,n)
```

The original expression is

[image]

Is there any way to make the request less demanding of memory or to fix this bug?

Comment: Doing `syms l` first, then defining the function, then running `fn(2,4)` gives me 42024 as the answer.  Are you sure it's a memory error?  Did you try with smaller inputs?  How about `fn(2,1)` or `fn(1,2)`?

Comment: yea i did first steps of declaration but even smaller values cudnt work may this because im running an elder version of matlab ??

Comment: That could possibly be it.  I'm using R2013a on Mac OS.  Which version are you running, and what operating system?

Comment: 2010 on windows with 2 G of RAM

Comment: hmmm.  OK, do me a favour.  Do `Ctrl+Alt+Del` and go to your Task Manager.  Go to the `Processes` tab, and locate the MATLAB program.  Run the command that you showed me, and see if the memory increases.

Comment: now i got this

??? Error using ==> factorial at 17
N must be a matrix of non-negative integers.

Error in ==> @(k,n)symsum((-1)^l*factorial(2^l)/factorial(2^l-2^k),l,k,n)

Comment: iv closed some windows and rebooted my pc but the error remains !!! wierd

Comment: What??? What values of `k` and `n` did you use?

Comment: fn(1,2) and fn(2,4) .... all positives

Comment: here is the sequence 

syms l integer ;

syms k integer ;

syms n integer ;

fn = @(k,n) symsum((-1)^l*factorial(2^l)/factorial(2^l-2^k),l,k,n)

Comment: Do **not** invoke `k` and `n` to be `syms`.  Do this only: `syms l; fn = @(k,n) symsum((-1)^l*factorial(2^l)/factorial(2^l-2^k),l,k,n); f(2,4)`.  What do you get after this?

Comment: same response ..... ps: i used fn not f as u mentionned

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: i think my matlab is gettin nuts hahaha

Comment: Did you do what I suggested with your Task Manager?  Does the memory increase when you run the code?

Comment: it was increasing by 10 000 K not an amount to take seriously

Comment: That is certainly weird.... 10 MB isn't something to worry about.

Comment: first off .... it was memory deal but when iv released more live memory space the error morphed!!!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why you're getting that error.

Comment: i ll try to update my version seems this will spare me some outdated problems

Comment: the newer release could cover that flaw may be